# Python List Values

Tags: python, list

I found an older example of this but in Python 3.0 it didn't seem to work. I have a basic list with 3 items. If I want to test x in `myList`, I can see if a user input a number that exists in the list, if they do that correctly I want to correlate each item in the list with a number value. How do I do this?

```
myList = ['a','b','c']
#say i want a = 27, b = 14 and c = 34

x = input("Letter please: ")
if x in myList:
    print("you got it!")
    print(#This is where I want item: a,b or c to be equal to a certain value)
else:
    print("Nope!")
```

How do I set `a`,`b` and `c` to a value while still being in the list and without just making 3 new variables?

Comment: Your problem is not clear at all.

Comment: Your using the wrong data structure. Use a `dict()`.

Comment: What exactly didn't work in Python3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a dictionary?

```
mydict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

x = input("Letter please: ")
if x in mydict:
    print("you got it!")
    print(mydict[x])
else:
    print("Nope!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a dictionnary instead of a list for "myList" :

```
myDict= {'a':27,'b':14,'c':34}
#say i want a = 27, b = 14 and c = 34

x = input("Letter please: ")
if x in myDict:
    print("you got it!")
    print(myDict[x])
else:
    print("Nope!")
```

Answer (score 0):

using a dict structure is what you're looking for. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

```
myList = {'a':27,'b':14,'c':34}

...

if x in myList.keys():
    ...
    print("Value is: " + str(myList[x]))
...
```

Comment: Alternatively, `if x in myList:`. You don't need to call `.keys()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your using the wrong data structure. Don't use a list. The exact behavior you describe can be found using a dictionary (or sometimes called an associative array in other languages). Dictionaries allow values to be mapped to other values. In your case, mapping strings to numbers:

```
d = {'a': 27,'b': 14,'c': 34}

x = input("Letter please: ")
if x in d:
    print("you got it!")
    print(d[x])
else:
    print("Nope!")
```